# Local Host / Spotify Redirect URI

Tags: r, api, redirect, spotify

For months now I'm using the `http://localhost/` URL as a redirect URI that is needed to access Spotify's API via R. For some reason it stopped working while nothing was changed re. the application settings. I'm not able to assess the localhost URL in my browsers either.

The API gives the following error message `INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI`. The Safari brows tells me that it can't connect to the server.

Any idea why this suddenly stopped working and both the API and my browsers won't proces the `http://localhost/` URL?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried: `"http://localhost:8000"` ? set redirect with the `:8000 part`at the end of  the URL, change it in the web configuration, in your authorization, and try again, please.